# Ruby: Accessing array's in arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, recursion

```
tourney = [
  [
    [ ["Armando", "P"], ["Dave", "S"] ],      
    [ ["Richard", "R"], ["Michael", "S"] ]
  ],
  [
    [ ["Allen", "S"], ["Omer", "P"] ],
    [ ["David E.", "R"], ["Richard X.", "P"] ]
  ],
]
```

That is a tournament that needs to be solved by the following code:

```
def self.winner(player1, player2)
  p1c = player1.last.downcase
  p2c = player2.last.downcase
  unless RPS.include?(p1c) && RPS.include?(p2c)
    raise NoSuchStrategyError, "Strategy must be one of R,P,S"
  end
  if p1c!=p2c 
    case p1c
      when "r" 
        p2c=="s" ? player1 : player2
      when "p" 
        p2c=="r" ? player1 : player2
      when "s" 
        p2c=="p" ? player1 : player2
    end
   else 
     player1
  end  
end
```

Now the base case is, of course,

```
def self.tournament_winner(tournament)
  if tournament.size == 2
    self.winner(tournament[0], tournament[1])
  else
    #WORK HERE
  end
end
```

But in the *else* how can I get the first array set being the array containing "Armando" and "Dave" check who wins then continue, it needs to be used on arbitrary sized arrays.
is there a way to go through the elements and filter the wins; i.e.,
 on the first instance of recursion it should return:

```
tourney = [
  [
    ["Dave", "S"],      
    [ ["Richard", "R"], ["Michael", "S"] ]
  ],
  [
    [ ["Allen", "S"], ["Omer", "P"] ],
    [ ["David E.", "R"], ["Richard X.", "P"] ]
  ],
]
```

I'm sorry if my wording's bad.  I've been trying to solve this for a while and its getting late and I lack sense.

Comment: Looks like EdX or Coursera exercise.  My hint would be to flatten it to some extent.

Comment: EdX it is, i've been stuck on this for a while i took a course based on recursion and the language allowed .first .rest which helped a lot but i dont know how to do this. Its a specification that it uses recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That base function is not correct. First, let us assume that the `tourney` array is well-formed with always pairs of either players or arrays. What you want to do is if `tournament[0]` is a simple player definition then player 1 is `tournament[0]`. However, if `tournament[0]` is an array of players, then player 1 is the winner of `tournament[0]` - this is your recursion. Repeat the same logic for player 2, and return the winner of player 1 versus player 2.

Now, the question becomes "How do I determine if `tournament[0]` is a simple array or not?" Lets do this the simple way with the interactive shell (I prefer `pry` over the default `irb`), using your second example:

```
[3] pry(main)> tourney.class
=> Array
[4] pry(main)> tourney[0].class
=> Array
[5] pry(main)> tourney[0][0].class
=> Array
[6] pry(main)> tourney[0][0][0].class
=> String
```

So, we can test the `.class` method to check if it is an array, leading us to this solution:

```
def self.tournament_winner(tournament)
  if tournament[0][0].class == Array
    player1 = self.tournament_winner(tournament[0])
  else
    player1 = tournament[0]
  end

  if tournament[1][0].class == Array
    player2 = tournament_winner(tournament[1])
  else
    player2 = tournament[1]
  end

  self.winner(player1, player2)
end
```

Note that I need to use `tournament[0][0]` to stop us recursing one step too deep. Actually, I don't like that, so lets try it another way, using [flatten](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten) as suggested above. We have reached the bottom of the tree if the flattened array is the same size as the unflattened version:

```
def self.tournament_winner(tournament)
  if tournament[0].flatten(1).size != tournament[0].size
    player1 = self.tournament_winner(tournament[0])
  else
    player1 = tournament[0]
  end

  if tournament[1].flatten(1).size != tournament[1].size
    player2 = tournament_winner(tournament[1])
  else
    player2 = tournament[1]
  end

  self.winner(player1, player2)
end
```

I use `flatten(1)` as a minor optimisation. Now:

```
[7] pry(main)> puts "And the winner is #{tournament_winner(tourney)[0]}!"
=> And the winner is Richard!
```

---

Further Ruby-fication of the function above might be

```
def self.tournament_winner(tournament)
  player1 = if tournament[0].flatten(1).size != tournament[0].size
    self.tournament_winner(tournament[0])
  else
    tournament[0]
  end
  
  player2 = if tournament[1].flatten(1).size != tournament[1].size
    tournament_winner(tournament[1])
  else
    tournament[1]
  end

  self.winner(player1, player2)
end
```

Or getting DRYer:

```
def self.get_competitor(branch)
  if branch.flatten(1).size != branch.size
    self.tournament_winner(branch)
  else
    branch
  end
end

def self.tournament_winner(tournament)
  player1 = self.get_competitor(tournament[0])
  player2 = self.get_competitor(tournament[1])

  self.winner(player1, player2)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me to understand the recursive functionality here I was really struggling on this

Comment: How long did it take you to come up with this algorithm?